# MongoDB $match in a aggregate lookup not working as expected

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql

When i run this query:

```
db.friendRequests.aggregate([
        $lookup: {
          from: "users",
          localField: "author",
          foreignField: "_id",
          pipeline: [
            {
              $match: {
                $expr: {
                  friend_id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userid),
                },
              },
            },
          ],
          as: "userdata",
        }
])
```

It returns every entry in the collection, but theres a pipeline in it. Then why is it not working?

Can you help me? Thanks!

**Playground:**
https://mongoplayground.net/p/Eh2j8lU4IQl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `friend_id` field is present in the `friendRequests` collection (source for the aggregation) *not* the `users` collection which is the target for the `$lookup`. Therefore that predicate should come in a `$match` stage that precedes the `$lookup`:

```
db.friendRequests.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "friend_id": ObjectId("636a88de3e45346191cf4257")
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "users",
      localField: "author",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "userdata"
    }
  }
])
```

See how it works in [this playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0yXMo266nIX). Note that I changed `inventory` to `users` assuming that was just a typo in the collection name in the provided playground link.

---

##### Original answer

This syntax is incorrect:

```
$match: { 
  $expr: {
    friend_id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userid),
  },
}
```

You should change it to either

```
$match: { 
  friend_id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userid),
}
```

Or

```
$match: { 
  $expr: {
    $eq: [ 
      "$friend_id", new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userid)
    ]
  },
}
```

Comment: None of them are working

Comment: Returns an empty ```userdata```

Comment: Can you please update your question with the (text) sample documents?

Comment: Im sorry, with what?

Comment: The sample documents that you are using, in _text_ format. We need to be able to reproduce the problem to assist. Even better if you could just share a [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/) example that has your documents loaded into it. Also, what is the value of `userid` in your code and where is it coming from? I see no other references to it in your question at all, which might be why nothing is matching.

Comment: the userid is coming from the frontend (angular) and its working. Even if a hardcode the id its not working

Comment: From the screenshots, the documents in the `users` collection do **not** contain a `friend_id` field which will be another reason that the aggregation is not working the way that you want it to. I would love to assist further, but I am unable to do so without sample documents (in a format that can be copy pasted) or a playground where I can reproduce the problem. Please let us know if you edit your question to include that information. See also why [images aren't helpful](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Comment: is it good if i send you the exported collections?

Comment: i created a mongoplayground link if its useful

Comment: Great, thanks! Can you also provide us with an example value for `userid`?

Comment: I updated the link with a hard-coded userid

Comment: when its working it should return 2 requests, bc the third is an outgoing request

Comment: Your solutions works thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

For mongodb version under 5.0 (Thanks for the remark @user20042973):
`$lookup` with `localField` and `foreignField` will ignore a `pipeline`. Remove them and add a `let` key in order to enable the pipeline.

Comment: And how do i use the ```let``` key?

Comment: I don't think this is correct as of `5.0` @nimrod serok, see [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#correlated-subqueries-using-concise-syntax)